# How can I disable JS minification during WordPress plugin development?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin that inserts some JavaScript into the head section of the page during the wp_head action. I finally figured out (I think?) that WordPress is automatically minifying any inline script I generate.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_head' );

function my_head() {
  echo "<script>alert('Hello');// This is a comment</script>";
}
```

What I end up with in my page is:

```
<script>alert('Hello');</script>
```

Note the comment is stripped out. Also all whitespace is stripped out.

I'd like to be able to debug this using a non-minified version, but I can't figure out how to disable JavaScript minification for my site, pages, plugin, or anywhere for that matter.

I am using a Bitnami WordPress 4.5 Amazon Machine Image, and have zero active plugins other than the one I am developing. Is minification built into the WordPress core somewhere?

How can I track down where minification is occurring so I can disable it?

Comment: WordPress does not minify JS by default. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Thanks @bugnumber9 - I updated the question with simplified code.

Comment: Are you using any external libs or components in your plugin?

Comment: Alternatively, your theme may contain something like http://setuix.com/minify-javascript-html-wordpress-without-plugin/ Change to default theme to check if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks bugnumber9 - I am using the standard hello world installation page and theme with all the defaults.

Comment: Check my answer below, that's where the devil is :)

Answer (score 0):

What could do minification:

- A plugin in wordpress
- A content delivery network
- Someting in your dev process like grunt or gulp
- Someting on your server ^_^

Try to disable/stop them

Comment: The question states that no other plugins are active, that the JavaScript is inline so could not be in a CDN, and could not be something in my dev process because the code is hard-coded in the plugin.

Comment: I juste try it on a standard wordpress install and the output in the html page is : `<script>alert('Hello');// This is a comment</script>`

Comment: [I replicate your issue](http://ec2-52-91-66-142.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) - 1 hour demo of Bitmini instance of Wordpress

Comment: Don't know how to solve it, but the minification come from Bitmini version of WP

Comment: Thank you so much Jordane! I'll see if I can contact someone at Bitnami or maybe use another version of WordPress.

Comment: Yep, the answer of @bugnumber9 is your solution :-)